# Child Components with rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Context

I have in my project two elements. A `player` (just a cube) and some `eyewears`.

When the glasses aren't attached to the player, i want them to have properties of a `Rigidbody`. But when the eyewears are attached to the player, i want them to be a static object, so the player can process the collisions and physics.

### I have tried:

`DestroyElement(rigidbody)` when the player pickup the eyewears. When he leaves them, i recreate the rigidbody with `AddComponent`

It worked nice, but in the future other elements will be attached and they will not share the same properties of rigidbody. I though maybe i could save the rigidbody instance, so when the player leaves the glasses i assign it to them. I could't.

`AddComponent` don't accept arguments.

---

Then i tried to set "kinematic mode" when my player wears the eyewears. It didn't go well, my player can't jump anymore and sometimes he glitches in the floor.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: "Is Kinematic" should physically work just like a gameobject with no rigidbody. Check that no joints use the eyewears as a connected body and also disabling the collider of the eyewears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to R Astra i checked again the eyewear collisions and i found out the problem. I had enabled the Convex mesh.

[image]

The col was causing trouble because the back meshes were inside the player

---

So, quickly i copied that eyewear and generate a new mesh. It worked!

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**[GameObject.AddComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)** does take an argument, or a generic argument (preferred):

```cs
go.AddComponent<RigidBody>();
```

this is also possible, but deprecated, since you lose type-safety:

```cs
go.AddComponent(typeof(RigidBody));
```

However, RigidBody is not meant to be added/removed, and in your case I would say that *kinematic mode* is the way to go... but I can't tell why you're experiencing weird results with it.

Comment: Thanks Hugo for pointing me in the right way. I manage to make it work using kinematic mode, as you suggested.